# Aws dynamodb auto scale price

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

When I use Aws dynamodb, I didn't know how the service calculate the cost with auto scale in each hour.

example:
 If first 12 "minutes" the write unit is 10 WCU, after that write unit is 
 20 WCU in one hour.

What is actual write unit should I pay? (10, 20 or 10 * 0.2 + 0.8 * 20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's specific examples of this at https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing, and in short you will pay for the maximum capacity units in a given hour when scaling up, and the target capacity units when scaling down.

Comment: Thank, i ask question, because i want to query a lot of data and that means i need to split query with limit parameter if i want to reduce the cost (It confused me , should i do that....).